# what are the alternatives for "Vigorously"?

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering if my sentence is correct and if it sounds ok for native speakers?

> Oh John, you are exercising vigorously today. Good on you!

What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Is this meant to be for Australians?  "Good on you" (or rather ["Good on ya"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5B157GORVo)) is a typical Aussie expression.  If that's the case then "vigorously" might sound OK down under, but it's a little odd to my American ears.

We Americans would probably substitute "hard" for "vigorously":

> The coach made the team exercise **hard** today.

although this would sound a little less formal if you use "work out" instead of "exercise"

> The coach made the team **work out** hard today.

Or, alternately

> The coach gave the team a **hard workout** today.

In your sentence:

> Hey John, been working out hard today?  Good for you!